# How to use "getElementById" inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I´m trying to use the following html DOM inside a loop:

```
document.getElementById('someID').style.marginLeft = mov + "%";
```

I want to do this to give movement to a div  when user clicks a button.
'mov' is variable, but it doesn´t work.

How can I achieve it?

Thank you all.

Comment: You should show how you're using that code in a loop/when a button is clicked since that's what your question is about.

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Yes, but the problem might be with the click handler which is why it's important to see all the relevant code.

Comment: "How to use “getElementById” inside a loop?" - not at all. You use it before the loop, store the value to a variable, and use the variable in a loop. Else (unless you have a modern browser that might optimize crap away) you use a lot of function calls to retrieve always the same element. That's wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS

```
#someID {
    margin-left: 100px;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}
#someID.moveit {
    margin-left: 500px;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}
```

Then add the `.moveit` class to `#someID` when the click occured.

Comment: Thank you very much, only with `transition: 1s ease-out;` works just as I wanted,

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pos = 50;

setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("someID").style.left=pos+"%";
},200);

document.body.onclick=function(e){
  pos = e.pageX/10 // window.innerWidth;
}
```

```css
#someID{
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

body{
  height:800px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="someID">  </div>
```

there is a simple example.

hope it helps.